# Please define a stack overflow exception -- c#

Tags: c#, function, methods, compiler-errors, stack-overflow

I'm not exactly sure what a stack overflow exception is.  I got this error when I called a method in another form.

Comment: It'd be better if you posted some code -- that way we could do what we're really here for: help you fix your exception, not define easily searchable terms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes programs misbehave.  Programmers write their programs by implementing some logic and then testing that it works correctly.  But if the programmer makes a mistake in the logic, bad things can happen.

Probably one of the most common ways that a program can go awry is with an infinite loop.  Take this sample program that tries to add up the first *n* integers:

```
static int Sum(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= n)
        sum += i;
    return sum;
}
```

What will happen?  Where's the bug?  We forgot to  increment `i` and so it will never exceed `n`.  When you just run this it runs and hangs.  It will never stop on its own.

But if you have an infinite loop in a program and you use **resources** in that loop, you could run out of resources.  Let's take another program that uses recursion to find the sum:

```
static int RecursiveSum(int n)
{
    return n + RecursiveSum(n - 1);
}
```

This method is also buggy.  It too has an "infinite loop" because we forgot to include the termination condition.  What happens when we run it?

> Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.

In C# every time you call a method you use up a little of a resource called a stack.  The stack allows the program to keep track of who called who so that when methods return, it returns to the right place.  Method arguments and local variables also use up stack space.  When methods end and return, they free up the stack space that they used.

The problem is that the stack uses memory and so it is not an infinite resource like time!

So there are two primary ways that a program can produce a `StackOverflowException`:

1. An infinite loop of methods calling methods calling methods that never return
2. A series of too many recursive call levels that **would** end eventually, but the stack runs out first

The first problem is demonstrated by the second method above.  But even if we fix that method to add a termination condition, while it will work for smaller numbers it will eventually fail before producing a sum for sufficiently large values of *n*.

Most garden variety `StackOverflowException`s are of the first type but if you don't use recursion carefully in your methods you can run into the second problem as well.

When debugging a `StackOverflowException` the call stack will often look like this:

```
...
Program.RecursiveSum(int n = -7770) Line 26 + 0xf bytes C#
Program.RecursiveSum(int n = -7769) Line 26 + 0xf bytes C#
Program.RecursiveSum(int n = -7768) Line 26 + 0xf bytes C#
Program.RecursiveSum(int n = -7767) Line 26 + 0xf bytes C#
Program.RecursiveSum(int n = -7766) Line 26 + 0xf bytes C#
The maximum number of stack frames supported by Visual Studio has been exceeded.
```

or sometimes `A` calls `B` which calls `C` and then calls `A` again, etc.  You just have to find the loop, set a breakpoint in in, a diagnose what is going on.

Comment: Of course, if C# had a tail-call emitting compiler, it might *not* stackoverflow on this example ;p

Answer (score 6):

A [**stack overflow**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) occurs when you have too many methods calling each-other.

Whenever your code calls a function, the runtime pushes an entry to a *call stack* marking where you were up to when you called the function.  When the function finishes, the runtime pops the ntry off of the stack and goes back there.

A stack overflow happens when this stack gets full.

Answer (score 1):

A stack overflow is when you run out of stack space.  Stack space is typically consumed by a method call, where argument values are pushed onto the stack (when the method returns they are popped/removed from the stack).  The most common case where you get a stack overflow is when you have some kind of recursion (a method that calls itself).  On each method call, you consume a little more stack space, until you run out -- that is when you get the stack overflow.